# How do I check a key press in Java?

Tags: java, input, io, javafx

Basically, I'm learning Java and I'm trying to make a simple game in Netbeans using JavaFX. Right now I have a window set up with a rectangle drawn in it. (I have a canvas set up to draw on.) I have made a player class and global class, but I need to know how to read key inputs. I was taught by a friend who is REALLY good with Java, so the info he gives me is good. I read up on KeyEvent, but I have no clue how to implement it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something like [Handling keyboard events with event handlers](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/KeyboardExample.java.htm) and [Working with Event Handlers](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/handlers.htm) for a more conceptual option

Comment: You might want to take a step back if you are having trouble reading the documentation/material. Maybe you need to familiarize yourself with other concepts before trying to get hands on with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same question some weeks ago. The problem was about how to check at any time if a key is being held down or not. There are various solutions, I solved it by using a bitset:

```
package game.input;

import java.util.BitSet;

import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

public class Input {

    /**
     * Bitset which registers if any {@link KeyCode} keeps being pressed or if it is released.
     */
    private BitSet keyboardBitSet = new BitSet();

    // -------------------------------------------------
    // default key codes
    // will vary when you let the user customize the key codes or when you add support for a 2nd player
    // -------------------------------------------------

    private KeyCode upKey = KeyCode.UP;
    private KeyCode downKey = KeyCode.DOWN;
    private KeyCode leftKey = KeyCode.LEFT;
    private KeyCode rightKey = KeyCode.RIGHT;
    private KeyCode primaryWeaponKey = KeyCode.SPACE;
    private KeyCode secondaryWeaponKey = KeyCode.CONTROL;

    Scene scene;

    public Input( Scene scene) {
        this.scene = scene;
    }

    public void addListeners() {

        scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyPressedEventHandler);
        scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, keyReleasedEventHandler);

    }

    public void removeListeners() {

        scene.removeEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyPressedEventHandler);
        scene.removeEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, keyReleasedEventHandler);

    }

    /**
     * "Key Pressed" handler for all input events: register pressed key in the bitset
     */
    private EventHandler<KeyEvent> keyPressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {

            // register key down
            keyboardBitSet.set(event.getCode().ordinal(), true);

        }
    };

    /**
     * "Key Released" handler for all input events: unregister released key in the bitset
     */
    private EventHandler<KeyEvent> keyReleasedEventHandler = new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {

            // register key up
            keyboardBitSet.set(event.getCode().ordinal(), false);

        }
    };


    // -------------------------------------------------
    // Evaluate bitset of pressed keys and return the player input.
    // If direction and its opposite direction are pressed simultaneously, then the direction isn't handled.
    // -------------------------------------------------

    public boolean isMoveUp() {
        return keyboardBitSet.get( upKey.ordinal()) && !keyboardBitSet.get( downKey.ordinal());
    }

    public boolean isMoveDown() {
        return keyboardBitSet.get( downKey.ordinal()) && !keyboardBitSet.get( upKey.ordinal());
    }

    public boolean isMoveLeft() {
        return keyboardBitSet.get( leftKey.ordinal()) && !keyboardBitSet.get( rightKey.ordinal());  
    }

    public boolean isMoveRight() {
        return keyboardBitSet.get( rightKey.ordinal()) && !keyboardBitSet.get( leftKey.ordinal());
    }

    public boolean isFirePrimaryWeapon() {
        return keyboardBitSet.get( primaryWeaponKey.ordinal());
    }

    public boolean isFireSecondaryWeapon() {
        return keyboardBitSet.get( secondaryWeaponKey.ordinal());
    }

}
```